# Xcode 8 remove storyboard, new project layout looks weird

Tags: xcode, beta

I use Xcode 8.1 beta to create a new project, and remove storyboard.. it works but the view looks like this...[image]

Is there something i miss ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add splash screen to your project with 640x1136 size and name it as Default-568h@2x.png.

It must work!! :)